# Incremental deployment of WP8 from visual studio does nothing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, xap

I have a very strange problem with my project in VS 2010 for a WP8 application. Everytime I run from the IDE it doesn't deploy the updated .xap to the device (or emulator). If I try to deploy it from the IDE manually it goes through ok but doesn't do anything. It looks like it wants to do an incremental update but things there are no changes. If I manually run XapDeployCmd /update from the command line that works fine. Doing a rebuild from the IDE will work, or if I switch from debug to release it works.

I can change anything in my C# or XAML but if I just do a normal build, the changes aren't there! Creating a new project and using that to test is fine. My solution though contains several projects as I use DirectX. I tried recreating the main solution and the main project then added in my source code and I still get the same problem.

ANY ideas?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app from the phone? Perhaps something is corrupted with this installed app.

Comment: Yeah. The emulator isn't persistent, so each time you run the emulator you get a "new" phone. I've reinstalled windows 8 though because I recently bought a SSD and wanted a fresh install. Haven't seen the problem for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and so far I only get the new version installed, by deinstalling the older prior deplyoing the new one.